# Get multiple columns based on single column filter in Hbase

Tags: hbase

I have column family as `cf1`, and I want to access all the columns with in that row where `EqID='Eq1'`,
I have used **ValueFilter**, but it only return me the EqID column.

```
hbase(main):004:0> scan 'abc', { COLUMNS => ['cf1:Value', 'cf1:EqID'],FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:Eq1' )" }
ROW                   COLUMN+CELL                                               
 row1                 column=cf1:EqID, timestamp=1401092981867, value=Eq1
```

Above i got the row1 but not column **Value** ,Similarly with get,

```
get 'abc', 'row1', {FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:Eq1' )"}
   COLUMN                CELL                                                      
     cf1:EqID             timestamp=1401092981867, value=Eq1                        
    1 row(s) in 0.0120 seconds
```

I didn't get the value of **Value** column. Is it possible to get the value of other column,where the condition of 1 column meet? Is it possible or row key is the only way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SingleColumnValueFilter for this.

If you are using java then you can look the following code

```
HTable hTable = new HTable(conf, Bytes.toBytes("tableName"));

Filter f = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("EqID"), Bytes.toBytes("EqID"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("Eq1"));
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setFilter(f);

ResultScanner scanner = hTable.getScanner(s);

for (Result r : scanner)
 {
  System.out.println(Bytes.toString(r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("EqID"), Bytes.toBytes("EqID"))));
 }
```